# (PHP+MySQL) How can I echo the column name on a specific condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP 5.4 with a MySQL database.

This database represents a media library. The table I'm dealing with has one column, "Title", with obvious contents, and then a series of boolean columns, representing the availability of that title on a given platform. So a row looks like

*TITLE: "Curb Your Enthusiasm: The Game"

PS4: 0

Atari 2600: 1

Dreamcast: 0*

And so on.

The PHP code I would like to write be, in pseudocode,

1. Echo row[0] (title)
2. Cycle through other cells in the row
3. If the cell is '0' or NULL, do nothing
4. But if the cell is '1', echo the name of that column

So the result would be the echoing of

*Curb Your Enthusiasm: The Game* (Atari 2600, WonderSwan, Saturn)

It's the fourth statement that I can't quite work out. It seems to require the function mysqli_fetch_field, but I'm not sure of the syntax, and nothing I try after googling quite works.

I'd really appreciate any advice or examples someone could offer!

```
$database = mysqli_connect(SERVER,USERNAME,PASSWORD,'games'); 
$query = mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM games` WHERE NAME LIKE '%ZELDA%'"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) { 
    echo $row[0]; // Echo title 
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($row);$i++) { 
        if ($row[$i] === '1') { 
            // ???????
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Show us the PHP code you have so far, covering 1-3

Comment: @CrankyGoon http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=N64UM4mk

Answer (score 2):

Here is some rough untested code that should hopefully get you going.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
    $columns = array(); // this will track the additional columns we need to display
    foreach($row AS $column => $value) {
        if($column == "title") {
            echo $value; // this is the title, just spit it out
            continue;
        }

        if($value == 1) {
            // We have a column to display!
            $columns[] = $column;
        }
    }
    if(count($columns)) {
        // We have one or more column names to display
        echo " (" . implode(", ",$columns) . ")";
    }
}
```

Some things to point out:

1. Using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` will allow you access to column names along with the values, which is useful here.
2. Keep track of the columns you want to display in an array first, this makes it easier at the end of each loop to format the output.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it helped me a lot, and helped me understand dealing with DB queries. One weird bit, though: even though this code works, it seems to give me dozens of repeats of the desired result. I'm seeing "F-Zero X (N64) (N64) (N64) (N64) (N64) (N64) (N64) (N64) (N64)", and so on, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why. My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=a8TrhMGv), what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can do something like this:

```
// Simulates DB fetch
$titles = array(
    array(
        'TITLE'=>'Curb Your Enthusiasm: The Game',
        'PS4'=>0,
        'Atari 2600'=>1,
        'Dreamcast'=>0
    ),
    array(
        'TITLE'=>'Curb Your Enthusiasm: The Book',
        'PS4'=>1,
        'Atari 2600'=>1,
        'Dreamcast'=>0
    )
);

foreach($titles as $title){
    // get supported platforms
    $supportedPlatforms = array();
    foreach($title as $titleAttribute=>$titleValue){
        if($titleAttribute != 'TITLE' && $titleValue == 1)
            $supportedPlatforms[] = $titleAttribute;
    }

    echo $title['TITLE'] . ' (' . implode(', ', $supportedPlatforms) . ')' . "<br>";
}
```

Try running it here: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/pr6-fwt